# How to get auth handler info in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

In my application I am using multiple authentication handlers like application DB, LDAP and SAML. Now after successful authentication I am using `CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java` which extends `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` class which will be called after successful authentication. My question is how to get information about which handler has a successful authentication. I need this information because if it is an external user (LDAP, SAML) then I have to write a logic to replicate the user in application DB.

My configuation in configure global method:

```
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(ldapAuthoritiesPopulator)
            .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
            .userDetailsContextMapper(ldapUserDetailsContextMapper)
            .contextSource(getLDAPContextSource());`
```

Comment: How do you know the user is exist in DB, LDAP or SAML ? I think there must be a type(maybe different request url) to flag the user. You can set this to `Authentication` when do authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the info to authentication detail when do authenticated, or you can use different `Authentication` instances, e.g `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` for DB and LDAP(maybe need to create a new `Authentication` to separate them), `SAMLAuthenticationToken` for SAML.

Comment: Yes, you can, Please post more info about your security config? http security config